# Has asymptotic analysis become an archaic subject? If so, why?

Tags: soft-question, asymptotics

Every applied math survey book I have which was written before the 1980s has an extensive treatment of asymptotic analysis; some of the older physics and engineering literature uses it liberally. Yet asymptotics were never even mentioned in all my schooling. Has it become an archaic subject?

I understand that the advent of computers enables numerical solutions which can supplant some of asymptotic analysis' utility in applications, but it seems to me that the scaling arguments asymptotics are usually used to justify remain useful, even with more computational power available. Why has it disappeared?

Comment: look at a random theoretical physics paper and you will see that asymptotic analyis lively as ever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far from having disappeared, asymptotic analysis is the basis of many entire branches of pure mathematics: some examples with which I am most familiar with are [geometric group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_group_theory), [dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system), and the sub-branch of dynamical systems known as [chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory). I don't see asymptotic analysis going away any time soon.

Furthermore, dynamical systems and chaos theory have many deep connections with applied mathematics, via the flows that are generated by first order dynamical systems of the form $dx_1/dt = f_1(x_1,...,x_n)$, ..., $dx_n/dt = f_n(x_1,...,x_n)$, also via the connections with statistical mechanics and statistical thermodynamics.